# Python: Replacing Asterisk with a character inputted by end user (Hangman Game)

Tags: python

I've been trying to program a Hangman Game for my Computing assessment, and I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

Basically, the program asks for a word from the user, and then runs a loop to create a string of asterisks, the same length of the inputted word.

Once one of the correct characters is inputted by the user, it will replace an asterisk with the correct character, but in order with the word. For example, if the word is "lie", and the user enters "i", it will change "***" to "*i*".

Code as below.

```
def guess_part(word):
    lives = 6
    LetterCount = 0
    LetterMask = ""
    for x in range(len(word)):
        LetterMask = LetterMask + "*"
    print LetterMask
    while lives != 0 and LetterMask.find("*")!=-1:
        LetterGuess = raw_input("Enter a letter to guess?")
        LetterCount = 0
        for char in word:
            LetterCount = LetterCount + 1
            if LetterGuess == char:
                print "Good Guess."
                LetterMask = LetterMask.replace(LetterMask[LetterCount], LetterGuess)
                print LetterMask

def rand_word():
    from random import randrange #import the randrange function, from "random"
    random_words = ['extraordinary','happy','computer','python','screen','cheese','cabaret','caravan','bee','wasp','insect','mitosis','electronegativity','jumper','trousers'] #list of different words which can be used by the program for the end user to guess.
    word = random_words[randrange(0, 15)] #pick a random number, and use this number as an index for the list, "random_words".
    guess_part(word) #call the function, "guess_part" with the parameter "word"

def user_word():
    print "All words will be changed to lowercase."
    print "Enter the word you would like to guess."
    print ""
    validation_input = False #Setting the validation unput to "False"
    while validation_input == False: #while the validation input is not False, do below.
        word = raw_input("") #Ask for input, and set the value to the variable, "word".
        if word.isalpha(): #If word contains only strings, no numbers or symbols, do below.
            word = word.lower() #set the string of variable, "word", to all lowercase letters.
            guess_part(word) #call the function, "guess_part" with the parameter, "word".
            validation_input = True #Break the while loop - set validation_input to "False".
        else: #if the above isn't met, do the below.
            print "Word either contained numbers or symbols."

def menu():
    print "Hangman Game"
    print ""
    print "Ashley Collinge"
    print ""
    print "You will have 6 lives. Everytime you incorrectly guess a word, you will lose a life."
    print "The score at the end of the game, is used to determine the winner."
    print ""
    print "Would you like to use a randomly generated word, or input your own?"
    print "Enter 'R' for randomly generated word, or 'I' for your own input."
    decision_bool = False #Set the decision_bool to "False".
    decision_length = False #Set the decision_length to "False".
    while decision_bool == False: #While decision_bool equals "False", do below.
        decision = raw_input("") #Ask for input, value set to the variable "decision".
        while decision_length == False: #While decision_length equals "False", do below.
            if len(decision) == 1: #If the length of decision eqausl 1, do below.
                decision_length = True #Set decision_length to "True."
                decision = decision.capitalize() #Capitalize the string value of decision.
                if decision == "R": #if the value of decision, eqauls "R".
                    print "You chose randomly generated word."
                    print ""
                    print "Forwarding..."
                    decision_bool = True #Set decision_bool to "True".
                    print ""
                    rand_word() #Call the function, rand_word()
                elif decision =="I": #If decision equals "I", do below.
                    print "You chose to input your own word."
                    print ""
                    print "Forwarding..."
                    decision_bool = True #Set decision_bool to "False".
                    print ""
                    user_word() #Call the function, user_word()
                else:
                    print "You entered an incorrect value for the question. Try again."
            else:
                print "You entered an incorrect value for the question. Try again."

menu()
```

I've commented the majority of the code, but if there's anything that's a bit vague, I'll answer.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: What's the roadblock -- `guess_part()` not working? In what way(s)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to write out your whole program for you, but in short:

Assume `word` is the word (e.g. `word = 'liar'`). Then we need a function that translates a word and a set of guessed letters to a string of asterisks + letters that have been guessed.

```
def asterisker(word, guesses=[]):
    result = ""
    for letter in word:
        result += letter if letter in guesses else "*"
        # which does what the below does:
        # if letter in guesses:
        #     result += letter
        # else:
        #     result += "*"
    return result
```

Giving us:

```
In [4]: asterisker("liar")
Out[4]: '****'

In [7]: asterisker("liar", ["l", "r" ])
Out[7]: 'l**r'
```

I'd probably write it like this, though the original above may be better/clearer.

```
def asterisker(word, guesses=[]):
    return "".join(l if l in guesses else "*" for l in word)
```

EDIT: Also, as Mike noted (first), you do need to decrement "`lives`" if someone makes a wrong guess.

---

Additionally, here are a few tips that you can use while writing Python.

1) Don't use capitalized variables (like `LetterMask`); instead use `lettermask` or `letter_mask` if you want it to be read as two words.

2) Comments such as "`validation_input = False #Setting the validation unput to "False"`" aren't helpful, and serve to clutter your code. It's quite obvious that you're setting the variable to False, as that is exactly what the code says. In cases where what you're doing is more unclear, comments may be more useful. This (commenting) is actually one of the hardest parts of programming, and something I still struggle with.

3) You use `print ""`; if you're just looking to print a newline,  you can either simply use `print` (which will print a newline), or add a "`\n`" (a newline character; it's pretty cool) anywhere within a string you're printing to print a newline. Try it out to see what I mean.

4) Instead of testing boolean values like `if something == False` you can simply say `if not something`, which is much clearer. Similarly, if you're testing `if something == True` you can simply say `if something`.

5) In my solution above, I asked myself "what am I trying to get", not "how do I get from where I am to where I want to be". The difference is subtle, and you may be saying "Isaac's a moron", and I may not be phrasing this well, but it's an important difference (I think!)

Good luck learning Python/programming!

Comment: No need for the list in your `join` one-liner. Can write as `"".join(l if l in guesses else "*" for l in word)` to use a generator which should be quicker and save memory. In the long-hand version, you could also write `result += letter` instead of `result = result + letter` ?

Comment: Ah, good catch. I've been writing ruby daily for a few months now…it shows. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `char` names anything built-in.  Are you thinking of `chr`?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but not quite there. Here's a few hints:

1) You need to decrement `lives` in `guess_part()`

2) This:

```
LetterMask = LetterMask.replace(LetterMask[LetterCount], LetterGuess)
```

isn't working how you want it to. I would suggest something simple like replacing it with:

```
LetterMask = list(LetterMask)
LetterMask[LetterCount-1] = LetterGuess
LetterMask = "".join(LetterMask)
```

3) Also note (above) the "-1" in the letter count, since strings are 0-based you're off by one.

With these few tweaks you're mostly there.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your problem is with the `guess_part()` function, here's a version that works:

```
def guess_part(word):
    lives = 6
    # Make a mutable array of characters same length as word
    LetterMask = bytearray("*" * len(word))
    while lives > 0 and LetterMask != word:
        print LetterMask
        while True:
            LetterGuess = raw_input("Enter a letter to guess: ")
            if LetterGuess: break
        LetterGuess = LetterGuess[0] # only take first char if more than one
        if LetterGuess in LetterMask:
            print "Sorry, you already guessed that letter. Try again."
            countinue
        GoodGuess = False
        for i, char in enumerate(word):
            if char == LetterGuess:
                GoodGuess = True
                LetterMask[i] = char
        if GoodGuess:
            print "Good guess."
        else:
            print "Sorry, bad guess"
            lives -= 1
    GuessedWholeWord = LetterMask == word
    if GuessedWholeWord:
        print "Congratulations, you guessed the whole word!"
    else:
        print "Sorry, no more guesses. You're hanged!"
    return GuessedWholeWord
```